# **no me arroja el contenido que tengo en mi bd hacia mi textview, especificamente lo que tengo en el campo "name"**

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin

[![No muestra el contenido que tengo en el campo "name" de mi bd en mi textview, al seleccionar el tipo de categoría me carga los tipos de la cat mas no el nombre de los participantes que tengo en dicha tabla.][1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYXAp.png)

**[![ Aquí selecciono el tipo de categoría que tengo en la bd][2]][2]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj66K.png)

-[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYXAp.png
-[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj66K.png

Comment: Buenas, Jesús, bienvenido al sitio. Deberias pegar el código como texto formateado. Y explicar un poco más tu estructura de tablas y la relación entre ellas. Entiendo que por un lado tienes las categorías y por otro los participantes con una referencia a la categoría. No veo en tu código nada relacionado con esta segunda parte. Aunque no soy programador de Android, podría estar equivocado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.